# python local variable- when do I have to assign a value?

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

I'm an amateur programmer and would like to seek advice while learning codes. Here I encounter some issues.

I found that when I remove the comment "#X=3" and make it into a code from the below then the code works. Without X=3, the code results into UnboundLocalError.

Browsed online, it's related to global and local variable but I can't see how it's related. And when does X has to be denoted before the while loop? and why "for y in primes" doesn't need to pre-define "y"?

Main purpose of the code: count the # of prime numbers up to (num)

```
def count_primes2(num):
    primes = [2]
    #x = 3
    if num < 2:
        return 0
    while x <= num:
        for y in primes:  # use the primes list!
            if x%y == 0:
                x += 2
                break
        else:
            primes.append(x)
            x += 2
    print(primes)
    return len(primes)
```

Comment: Since you are using `x` in the while loop criteria, yes, it has to be defined before.

Comment: `for y in primes` itself defines `y`; a `for` loop is a kind of assignment statement.

Comment: @SuperStew, so it's a common practice for handling X before the while X loop? Can I briefly confirm that the var has to be denoted before every while loop?

Comment: @chepner, I see. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

As per design pattern variable should be created just before to use. In the code you are using x without creating or initializing default value.
"y" = you are iterating the list (primes). So in each iteration y will be initialized by the current value.So it will not give any error.

Answer (score 1):

To expand, since you are using x in the while loop criteria, yes, it has to be defined before. You don't need to define `y` before the for loop because the `for y in primes` line defines `y` as each item in the list.

A rough translation to plain English:

`while x <= num:` == As long as this number is less than or equal to this other number, do the following

`for y in primes` == do the following for each item, named y, in primes

hopefully that wasn't more confusing

Answer (score 1):

You need to create (and assign a value to) a variable before you use it.  If you try to use a variable's value *before* creating the variable, then you get the exception.  You do exactly this in the `while` expression: You ask if its value is below or equal to `num`, but it does not even exist yet, it has no value, this raises the exception.

Now, why do you get the `UnboundLocalError`?

The compiler goes through your code before the code gets executed.  In this compile step it notices that you *somewhere* in your function assign a value to `X`, namely in the line `x += 2`.  (There are even two of them.)  This marks the variable for the compiler as a *local* variable.

So if you try to access the variable *before* the assignment takes place, the variable doesn't exist yet, but the code already knows that is supposed to be a *local* variable, hence the `UnboundLocalError`.

Without *any* assignment statement to `X` in the function you would have gotten a `NameError` because during execution of the `while` statement the interpreter then searches for a global variable of this name.